# How to delete image from PHAssetCollection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I have PHAssetCollection in my application which contain all albums of photos app.

Problem is that i can delete images from the All Photos but cant delete images from camera roll,favourites,screenshots etc..

Plz help me to delete from PHAssetCollection.

this is the code i did to delete images.

```
// Enable the trash button if the asset can be deleted.
    BOOL isTrashable = NO;
   if (self.assetCollection) {
    isTrashable = [self.assetCollection canPerformEditOperation:PHCollectionEditOperationRemoveContent];
} 
   else {
     isTrashable = [self.asset canPerformEditOperation:PHAssetEditOperationDelete];
}
   self.trashButton.enabled = isTrashable;
   [self updateImage];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reference from [Apple developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest)

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *request = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest
                                                       changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.myAlbum
                                                       assets:self.albumAssetsFetchResult];
            [request removeAssets:@[asset]];

        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Finished removing asset from the album. %@", (success ? @"Success" : error));
        }];
```

or

```
 // Delete asset from library
        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[self.asset]];
        } completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

> make sure **isTrashable = YES**

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/ExampleappusingPhotosframework.zip (you have to be a registered developer to access this)     I use this code plz let me suggest where i have to put above code @Vvk Aghera

Comment: ==>> assets:self.albumAssetsFetchResult;  Can u tell me in this statement which thing i have to allocate assets.

Comment: plz can u solve this. Your answer is already in demo project but can u tell me why its not working?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya please check in Demo Code in flie AAPLAssetViewComtroller.M line no: 265--278. its allready worked.

Comment: But it will allow you delete image only from All Photos. If u want to delete image from Camera roll, delete is not allowed

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya please goto AAPLAssetViewComtroller.M line no:60
set isTrashable = yes
COMMENT LINE NO: 61,62,63,65
then
go to line no:265
Comment all code between line no 265 to 278 and add below code

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[self.asset]];
        } completionHandler:completionHandler];

Comment: Yaa thnks this is i already done. But i have confusion with those two different methods used for delete assets and assetscollection.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the above code and set

```
self.trashbutton.enable=YES;
```

Images deleted from camera role also deleted from All Photos.